# Dedicated AMD Graphics card not detected

Tags: 14.04, ati

I'm using Samsung 3rd gen intel i5 laptop with Radeon HD8750 and Intel HD4000, with Ubuntu 14.04

My laptop is currently using integrated graphics card only. It doesn't even mention about dedicated graphics card. I think both the graphics card are switched ON ,that's why my laptop is consuming more power and getting really hot.

On my earlier laptop I used bumblebee for this switching between the 2 graphics card. Is there any similar tool available for ATI, or is it possible to disable one of the card (No such option is provided in boot menu by samsung).

Please suggest something to resolve this issue. I can post the output of any command if you need it.

```
lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7d00000-f7dfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000efffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f7e1a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7e18000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f7e10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7e17000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7e16000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7e15000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at f7d40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device 4105
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f7c80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c706
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It probably is detected, looking at this bit of `lspci -v`:

> Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
>   ...
>   Kernel driver in use: radeon

You may able to turn it off by removing the `radeon` driver, or use `vga_switcheroo` as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics):

> ### Using vga_switcheroo
>
> Once you've ensured that vga_switcheroo is available, you can use
>   these options to switch between GPUs. Be prepared for a lockup (either
>   immediately, or after a minute), the existence of this file does not
>   mean that the machine is supported.
>
> ```
> echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Turns on the GPU that is disconnected (not currently driving outputs),
>   but does not switch outputs.
>
> ```
> echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Connects integrated graphics with outputs.
>
> ```
> echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Connects discrete graphics with outputs.
>
> ```
> echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Turns off the graphics card that is currently disconnected.
>
> There are also a couple of options that are useful from inside an
>   X-Windows session:
>
> ```
> echo DIGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Queues a switch to integrated graphics to occur when the X server is
>   next restarted.
>
> ```
> echo DDIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Queues a switch to discrete graphics to occur when the X server is
>   next restarted.
>
> ```
> cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> Allows you to verify the current state of the hybrid graphics.
>   Typically, there will be two lines of output - one should indicate
>   "Pwr" and the other should indicate "Off".

Note you have to run these commands as root with `sudo`. You can also check what it currently is set to do with the above `cat` command - example output *(note you can get which card is which by comparing the last sets of numbers to those from `lspci` next to the cards)*:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

I think if the only the integrated is set to be used, you can turn the discrete card off.

N.B. I tried getting just the AMD card to run on a 2nd gen Intel i5 laptop - this did not work as it was not connected to any of the video outputs... I had to SSH in to repair this. So having a SSH server running on the machine so you can access it remotely may be a good idea.